# How to add class to an element after js redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to open the modal after redirecting to the main page , but it didn't work.

```
            if ($password != $row['user_pwd']) { 
                echo '<script>
                location = "../index.php?error=lwrongPwd&username='.$uidemail.'";
                var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
                modal.classList.add("active");
                </script>';

                  exit();
            }
```

This open the page and not appearing the modal.

Comment: js code isnt persistent across page navigation. You cant run the code on one page and expect it to change the next page. you need to have the page being loaded do that

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you are using PHP, just redirect by writing:

```
header("Location: yourURLHere");
exit();
```

Besides that, you need to handle that optional class from the target page itself. There are two main ways:

- adding a GET parameter to your target URL and checking it from target page;
- adding a SESSION variable and unsetting it from target page once read.

You can either choose one option or combine both (e.g. a GET parameter to activate the checking process and a SESSION variable containing your desired message to be displayed). It is up to you and your needs though.

Comment: Thaank you much, that helped !